# Is there a way to import a Python file into wxGlade without a wxg backup?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxglade

I have a question about wxGlade, I made an interface and it works fine except that I deleted the backup of the wxg file. Is there any way to transfer a python file to a wxg file or to import it into wxGlade?

I tried to find xml file converters but it does not work with wxGlade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a proof of concept how to do this:
[https://sr.ht/~carstengrohmann/wxPython2wxGlade/](https://sr.ht/%7Ecarstengrohmann/wxPython2wxGlade/)